# Asus laptop suddenly stuck at UBUNTU loading screen

Tags: boot, screen, amd-graphics

My asus laptop suddenly stuck at UBUNTU loading screen, it keeps on loading for ever.
It flashes after 1 or 2 seconds with black screen and with some writing.

It has AMD graphics card.

So all the other solutions that I tried didn't work as they were for NVidia.

Seeking help

Comment: Why do you think that it might be linked to your graphic card? Is your laptop systematically stuck while booting?

Comment: All the solutions i watched relates to Nvidia users , so i thought i might mention mine , and it also shows "cant connect to display " for any command that needs to show something on screen

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is to use [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Choose it on GRUB screen by selecting `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.

[image: ubuntu recovery mode]

Then choose your kernel with `(recovery mode)` (should be second option)

On next screen choose `Drop to root shell prompt`

Log into root account. Then you can try to uninstall binary driver you've installed before or use `dpkg-reconfigure` to refresh its configuration.

Comment: I did and there was no error message , but still while booting the ubuntu logo goes away showing some black and white text.                      Last line :                                                                 
  [ ok ] Started Gnome Display Manager ..... and deal with any system changes  .pp link was shut down